# What is the difference between $(\mathcal{H}\setminus \{ 0\})/\mathbb{C}^*$ and $\mathcal{H}_1/U(1)$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, definition, normalization

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space. We define the [projective Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_Hilbert_space) $\mathbb{P}\mathcal{H}$ as $\mathcal{H}\setminus \{ 0\}/\mathbb{C}^*$. Then $[\Psi]=\{ z\Psi :z\in \mathbb{C}^*\}$.

On the other hand, we know that $U(1)$ acts on $\mathcal{H}_1 :=\{ \Psi \in \mathcal{H}:\langle \Psi |\Psi \rangle=1\}$. So we can construct $\mathcal{H}_1/U(1)$ and so we have $[\Psi]=\{ e^{i\theta}:\theta \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

What is the difference between $(\mathcal{H}\setminus \{ 0\})/\mathbb{C}^*$ and $(\mathcal{H}_1/U(1)$? Are they the same?

[image]

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: Also, the text you quoted already answers your question: It doesn't say to take the quotient $(H\setminus\{0\})/\mathrm{U}(1)$, it says to take *the unit sphere* in $H$ and quotient it by $\mathrm{U}(1)$.

Comment: @ACuriousMind You are right. I've made a mistake. Assume that $\mathcal{H}_1 :=\{ \Psi \in \mathcal{H}:\langle \Psi |\Psi \rangle =1\}$. Are $(H\setminus \{ 0\})/\mathbb{C}^*$ and $\mathcal{H}_1 /U(1)$ the same?

Comment: Yes - the proof is not hard, try it.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Thanks for the comment. Could you please tell me you mean they  are the same set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text mentions two definitions of the space of physical states. One is $\mathcal{H} \setminus \{0\}$ modulo $\mathbb{C}^*$, and the other is the unit sphere in $\mathcal{H}$ modulo $U(1)$. They are equivalent, there's no distinction between using one or the other.

The unit sphere $\mathcal{H}_1$ is the subset of vectors with absolute value 1; topologically, it's equivalent to $\mathcal{H} \setminus \{0\}$ quotiented by $\mathbb{R}^*$. This is because in this latter set, the equivalence class of a vector $\Psi$ is the set of all the nonzero real multiples of $\Psi$, which contains exactly one element of absolute value 1; and conversely, every element of the unit sphere is in one equivalence class, so there's a one-to-one correspondence.

Now, $\mathbb{C}^* = \mathbb{R}^* \times U(1)$, because a nonzero complex number has an amplitude and a phase. We can think of $(\mathcal{H}\setminus \{0\}) / \mathbb{C}^*$ as being done in two steps: first we quotient by $\mathbb{R}^*$ and get the unit sphere, and then we quotient by $U(1)$ and get the space of rays.

This is a bit extra, but strictly speaking $(\mathcal{H}\setminus \{0\}) / \mathbb{C}^*$ and $\mathcal{H}_1 / U(1)$ are homeomorphic, but they are not the same set. Both are sets of equivalence classes; but each equivalence class $[\Psi]$ in the first quotient has elements with arbitrary amplitude, while the equivalence class in the second quotient only has unit vectors. Still, there's a one-to-one correspondence between the two quotients, and I'm sure that there are topological theorems assuring that everything is continuous.

Comment: Dear @Javier thanks so much for the comment. I've put a part of a book concerning my question. Could you please tell my when we use $[\Psi]=\{ z\Psi :z\in \mathbb{C}^*\}$ and when we use $[\Psi]=\{ e^{i\theta}:\theta \in \mathbb{R}\}$ in quantum mechanics? I don't understand it.

Comment: Sorry. I've made a mistake in my question. I've edit it.

Comment: @Mahtab I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice explanation. I got it now. I appreciate you.